# OpenVPN server with internal DNS nameservers

Tags: dns, vpn, openvpn

I have a OpenVPN 2.4.6 x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu running on Centos 7 AWS ec2 instance.

I also have 2 internal company DNS nameservers that I can query internal hostnames from (working fine)

Whenever employees connect to our subnets via OpenVPN, I want their laptops to use our internal DNS nameservers for name resolution, but no matter how many combinations of configs I tried, I cant get the connecting client to use the internal DNS for name lookup (the client, Ubuntu, is using its local /etc/resolv.conf for lookups of internal hostnames, not our own DNS)

heres my openvpn server.conf,

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
user nobody
group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
keepalive 10 120
topology subnet
management 127.0.0.1 5555
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

push "redirect-gateway def1"
**push "dhcp-option DOMAIN company.ec2us"
push "dhcp-option DNS xxx.xxx.91.251"
push "dhcp-option DNS xxx.xxx.126.93"**

push "route 192.xxxx.xxx.0 255.255.255.0"  # ABC1 subnet
push "route 192.xxxxx.0 255.255.255.0"  # NYC office LAN
push "route 208.xxxx.0 255.255.255.0"  # XYZ internal

crl-verify crl.pem
ca ca.crt
cert server_v8OxxxxxxxFCOK.crt
key server_v8ORxxxxxx7FCOK.key
tls-auth tls-auth.key 0
dh dh.pem
auth SHA256
cipher AES-128-CBC
tls-server
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
status /var/log/openvpn/status.log
verb 3
```

the client OVPN file looks like this,

```
client
proto udp
remote xxx.xxx.155.45 1194
dev tun
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
verify-x509-name server_v8ORQmlxxxxFCOK name
auth SHA256
auth-nocache
cipher AES-128-CBC
tls-client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
dhcp-option DOMAIN company.ec2us
dhcp-option DNS xxx.xxx.91.251
dhcp-option DNS xxx.xxx.126.93

verb 3
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
```

xxxxxx
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
    
    
    Certificate:
     xxxxxx

I can see that the server is giving out the DNS options,

```
Wed Feb 27 17:06:48 2019 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1,dhcp-option DOMAIN company.ec2us,dhcp-option DNS xxx.xxx.91.251,dhcp-option DNS xxx.xxx.126.93,route xxx.xxx.40.0 255.255.255.0,route xxx.xxx.30.0 255.255.255.0,route xxx.xxx.251.0 255.255.255.0,route-gateway 10.8.0.1,topology sub
```

But once connected on the client, if I do nslookup $name-of-internal -host, its using my default 8.8.8.8 thats in my /etc/resolv.conf

Is there a way to force clients to use internal DNS hosts?